# How to use delegate between two ViewController without StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols, viewcontroller

I'd like to trigger a message from viewController to another viewController.
And I coded like below, but viewController didn't call delegate.
I want to call delegate without stroyboard. I just want to send a message to another viewController.

viewController2.h

```
@protocol ViewController2Delegate;

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewController2Delegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol ViewController2Delegate <NSObject>
- (void)showSomethingByDelegate;
@end
```

viewController2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate showSomethingByDelegate];
}

@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()
<ViewController2Delegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
    vc2.delegate = self;

}
// Below method was not called by delegate.
- (void)showSomethingByDelegate {
    NSLog(@"Button Was Pressed!!!");
}


@end
```

Comment: and I presume there __must be__ a snippet somewhere when `vc2` actually goes into the navigation stack... or by any chance, would you have a _different_ instance of `ViewController2` what goes to the stack eventually and by any change the delegate has not been set at all for that?

Comment: How do you navigate to "ViewController"?

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
```

This line of code is not doing what you think it is, this is creating a NEW instance of `ViewController2` and storing it inside the variable `vc2`. At no point (based on your code) is this variable added to the navigation stack and displayed on screen.

**Edit**
Also as noticed by Holex, your `vc2` variable will be removed from memory after the `viewDidLoad` is finished as you are not holding onto a reference of it. You would either need to create a property to hold onto it, or push it onto the navigation stack for the navigationController to hold onto it.

There are multiple ways to solve this issue:

1. Instead of creating a new `viewController2`, find a reference to the one already displayed on the screen (if it is on the screen).
2. If its not on the navigation stack, add `vc2` to the navigation stack `[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];` (assuming you have a navigation controller).
3. If not on the stack, and not intending to use a navigationController, present `vc2` modally, such as `[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: you could also mention that the local `vc2` (the instance) is basically released immediately after the `-viewDidLoad` runs out of its scope, and they need to keep the instance alive by a reference which is _outside_ of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

well let me show an example more simple.

**File: firstVC.h**

```
/* This define the protocol object,
 you can write methods required or optional the diference is when
 the protocol is used in a class, xcode show you a yellow warning with required methods
 like UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate... */

@protocol firstVCDelegate <NSObject>

@required
- (void)didMessageFromOtherViewController: (NSString *)messageStr;

@optional
- (void)didOtherMessageNotRequired: (NSString *)messageStr;

@end

/* This is the definition of first UIViewController */

@interface firstViewController : UIViewController
@end


/* This is the definition of second UIViewController object with
 a property that is our protocol 'firstVCDelegate' */

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <firstVCDelegate> firstVCDelegate;

- (void)executeDelegateProcess;

@end
```

**File: firstVC.m**

```
#import "firstVC.h"

#pragma mark - First UIViewController with delegate

@interface firstViewController() <firstVCDelegate>
@end

@implementation firstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Creating the 'secondViewController' object with delegate on this class
    secondViewController *svc = [secondViewController new];

    // Assign the delegate class
    [svc setFirstVCDelegate: self];

    // Run the delegate logic
    [svc executeDelegateProcess];
}

- (void)didMessageFromOtherViewController:(NSString *)messageStr
{
    // Receiving the message from the instance of our protocol in the 'secondViewController' class
    NSLog(@"MESSAGE #1: %@", messageStr);
}

- (void)didOtherMessageNotRequired:(NSString *)messageStr
{
    // Receiving the message in optional method
    NSLog(@"MESSAGE #2: %@", messageStr);
}

@end

#pragma mark - Second UIViewController

@implementation secondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)setFirstVCDelegate:(id<firstVCDelegate>)firstVCDelegate
{
    if (firstVCDelegate)
        _firstVCDelegate = firstVCDelegate;
}

- (void)executeDelegateProcess
{
    // This method is only for demo
    // You can execute your delegate in the way you need to use

    if (_firstVCDelegate) {
        [_firstVCDelegate didMessageFromOtherViewController: @"Hello world, using the required method from secondViewController class"];

        [_firstVCDelegate didOtherMessageNotRequired: @"Hello code using the optional method"];
    }
}

@end
```

In your **appDelegate.m** in the method **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** you can put this, and you need to **#import "firstVC.h"**

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        [_window setRootViewController: [firstViewController new]];
```

Execute and see two logs messages, I hope I've helped :)